# Running Deploy Hook via bin/magento-docker ece-deploy results with Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/ece-tools returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: magento2.4, installation, localhost, docker, deploy

I am trying to get a project that is already live in production setup and installed on my local for development. After running my `bin/magento-docker up -d` all of my containers start successfully. But when I use the following command:

`sudo bin/magento-docker ece-deploy`

I am getting the following output and error:

```
[+] Running 4/0
 ⠿ Container my-current-magento2-project-db-1             Running                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container my-current-magento2-project-elasticsearch-1  Running                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container my-current-magento2-project-rabbitmq-1       Running                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container my-current-magento2-project-redis-1          Running                                                                     0.0s


    Running "deploy" hook.
    Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/ece-tools
    returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I checked out my `.magento.app.yaml` file at at line 84 I see the following:

```
 # We run deploy hook after your application has been deployed and started.
deploy: |
    php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools deploy
```

This is as far as I can get and after a bit of research I am stuck. Any insight on my issue or possible solutions would be great. Thanks!

***UPDATE***
So after connecting to my nginx container I am seeing my site files but I am not seeing ece-tools in the vender/bin folder (Which is empty).

**New Question**

How can I make sure these files are added to the web server container?